# Phonegap 2.7.0, executeScript, target: "_self" not working

Tags: cordova, target, self

I'm trying to use the new PhoneGap (version 2.7.0) function "executeScript" to insert som JavaScript-code to the page I'm loading to the child browser using the function "window.open".
- I do not want to show the "Navigation bar", which I understand only can be hidden by choosing the taget "_self" (shows automatically with target "_blank"?)

But when I change the target from "_blank" to "_self" the function (executeScript) stops working.

Working example:
            var ref = null;

```
        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            ref = window.open('the url', '_blank', 'location=no');
            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
                ref.executeScript({code: "alert('test');"});
            });
        }
```

Not working:
                var ref = null;

```
        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            ref = window.open('the url', '_self', 'location=no');
            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
                ref.executeScript({code: "alert('test');"});
            });
        }
```

The only difference is the target...

Does anyone know how to get the function working - with no navigation bar? Basicly I just want to use some of the built in API in Phonegap in my external page... (and use local.storage on the device).

Thanks!